# R with testthat: Get list of exported functions

Tags: r, unit-testing

I ship a text file with all exported functions listed. To make sure, that all functions are listed, I would like to create a unit test via `testthat` and compare all exported function with the one in the text file. My current approach reads in the file and compares it with `ls("package:myPackage")`. But this call returns a long list of all functions of all imported packages. Any ideas how to solve this?

A complete different approach would be to generate this file automatically. But I think the first approach is easier to realise. Hopefully.

Comment: One way to go about this would be to source the text file into a new environment and compare exported functions to your list.

Comment: All exported function will be in the `NAMESPACE` file (`export(function_name)`)

Comment: `ls(asNamespace("myPackage"))` should return all functions/variables in your package, *but* including unexported ones too. And there's `getNamespaceExports("myPackage")` too.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin I think, from this I can build a proper approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexis Unfortunately, in `testthat` both give me a bunch of functions, exported, unexported and functions from imported packages.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik What do you mean, with sourcing the text file? It doesn't contain R code.

Comment: Then, if I understand correctly, you will have to somehow parse the functions from the test file?

Comment: Please provide an example to work with

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Emmanuel-Lin here is my solution:

```
require(data.table)
test_that("Function List", {
  # read namespace and extract exported functions
  funnamespace = data.table(read.table(system.file("NAMESPACE", package = "PackageName"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  funnamespace[, c("status", "fun") := tstrsplit(V1, "\\(")]
  funnamespace[, fun := tstrsplit(fun, "\\)")]
  # read function list
  funlist = read.csv2(system.file("subdirectory", "functionList.txt", package = "PackageName"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # test
  expect_equal(funnamespace[status == "export", fun], funlist[, 1])
})
```

Obviously, I was too lazy to work out the correct regular expression to replace the two `tstrsplit` by one row.